# Android set styles to polish apps

Tags: android, xml, ios, layout, styles

looking at iOS, buttons automatically have tap blue glossy states, popups automatically have sleak borders, you can automatically click outside of popups to make them go away, and more

from an android perspective, these things look like everything has certain attributes attached to them.

so for android, are there any theme packages (series of xml layouts for custom dialogs, drawables with tap states for view elements) that are designed to polish apps?

I'm not looking for things like iOS, I am looking for things that polish an app, such as well thought out tap states, stylized borders etc.

clarification: for iOS, there exists communities that create packs of icons and tap states preconfigured for iOS and targeted to developers and designers for iOS. A lot of these things are easily ported to Android, but I am wondering if a community exists targeted toward android where they release these things, and already configured XML files etc

surprise me! insight appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can easily define your own theme's if you can't find any pre-made ones: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html

Comment: I am looking for a resource of pre-made ones. I hadn't previously considered it but now I am wondering if a community or repository like that exists for android. I think such a community could make some really polished themes for apps with much more flexibility than anything I've seen on iOS